# How do i join an array to itself when a certain value is repeated

Tags: php, arrays, db2

I have an array that contains items for an employee. Some employees have more than one record, therefore have more than one array. 
example. There could be a max of 5 records.

```
[7] => Array
    (
        [emp_num] => 13
        [emp_name] => SMITH, BILL                                  
        [appropriation1] => 51000550000              
        [hours1] => 80.00
        [sal/rate1] => 500.00
        [default_pay] => Y
        [total_hours] => 82.00
        [gross] => 537.50
    )

[8] => Array
    (
        [emp_num] => 13
        [emp_name] => SMITH, Bill                                  
        [appropriation1] => 51000550005              
        [hours1] => .00
        [sal/rate1] => .00
        [default_pay] =>  
        [total_hours] => 82.00
        [gross] => 537.50
    )
```

The [appropriation1],[hours1],[sal/rate1] are the only thing that will repeat. So I want to end up with

```
[7] => Array
   (
    [emp_num] => 13
    [emp_name] => SMITH, BILL                                  
    [appropriation1] => 51000550000
    [appropriation2] => 51000550005
    [appropriation3] => 51000550005
    [appropriation4] => 51000550005
    [appropriation5] => 51000550005              
    [hours1] => 80.00
    [hours2] => .00
    [hours3] => .00
    [hours4] => .00
    [hours5] => .00
    [sal/rate1] => 500.00
    [sal/rate2] => .00
    [sal/rate3] => .00
    [sal/rate4] => .00
    [sal/rate5] => .00
    [default_pay] => Y
    [total_hours] => 82.00
    [gross] => 537.50
)
```

Would this be easier to do in sql? I only know basic sql, but if I join the table to itself would I be able to create columns rather try to manipulate an array? Or even make a view?

Heres the basic sql

```
 select employeenumber,EMPLOYEENAME, APPROPRIATION, TOTALHOURS as hours, PAYSALRATE, DEFAULTPAYCODE
  from DET
  where RECTYPEIND = 'D'
```

Comment: try to store them in array again example $arr['sal/rate'][] = $srcARR['sal/rate']

Comment: have you tried something? please update code.

Comment: i tried a foreach using an if statement on emp_num == emp_num. but that will always be true. I tried array_merge, but I don't need the whole array.

Comment: can you please update that in your question

Comment: what if there would be 4 records for some employee? extend your input and final result